# Not getting retweets in response for statuses/friends_timeline twitter API Method

Tags: iphone, twitter, mgtwitterengine

Hi I am using MGTwitterEngine & when request for tweets of my followers I am not getting the tweets which are retweeted.

According to the twitter documentation :

include_rts    When set to either true, t or 1,the timeline will contain native retweets (if they exist) in addition to the standard stream of tweets. The output format of retweeted tweets is identical to the representation you see in home_timeline. Note: If you're using the trim_user parameter in conjunction with include_rts, the retweets will still contain a full user object.

I am also doing that. but no change in response.
My request is : https://twitter.com/statuses/friends_timeline/**xyz**.xml?include_rts=true&page=4&count=20

**xyz** is username.

I cannot figure out what's missing? Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?include_rts=true&page=4&count=20&screen_name=**xyz**

Note the leading "api."